# Didn't get array of users like in delete action WPList table in users tab

Tags: users, wp-list-table

I am adding a bulk action `assign` just like `delete`.

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-users', array( $this, 'add_bulk_action' ) );

/**
 * Add Bulk Assign Action.
 * @param  array    $actions    Current Actions.
 * @return array    All Actions along with assign action.
 */
public function add_bulk_action( $actions ) {
    $actions['assign'] = __( 'Assign', 'wp-assign' );

    return $actions;
}
```

However, while trying to trigger the assign action, I am not being able to get the users selected with checkbox.

```
add_action( 'load-users.php', array( $this, 'trigger_bulk_actions' ) );
public function trigger_query_actions() {
       print_r( $_REQUEST );
}
```

While triggering the delete action I can get users in `$_REQUEST`

```
[12-Oct-2018 13:36:56 UTC] Array
(
    [s] => 
    [_wpnonce] => c48578ebab
    [_wp_http_referer] => /professional/wp-admin/users.php?delete_count=18
    [action] => delete
    [new_role] => 
    [paged] => 1
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [action2] => -1
    [new_role2] => 
)
```

Why am I not getting users in my custom `assign` action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're handling the request incorrectly, `load-users.php` is not the correct hook

Instead, use `handle_bulk_actions-users`

```
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-users', 'sanzeeb_bulk_action_handler_user', 10, 3 );

function sanzeeb_bulk_action_handler_user( $redirect, $action, $object_ids ) {

    // let's remove query args first
    $redirect = remove_query_arg( array( 'assign' ), $redirect );

    // do something for "Assign" bulk action
    if ( $doaction == 'assign' ) {
        // ...
```

Some other notes:

- These are all very generic names `assign` `trigger_query_actions` etc, **prefix them** e.g. `sanzeeb_assign`, otherwise you'll clash with other plugins
- Avoid `$_REQUEST` for security reasons, it's not just GET and POST, it's also `COOKIE` `SESSION` etc